# Qual DocType uso no PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces

Fiz uma fusão de projeto utilizando PrimeFaces + PrimeFaces Mobile, e não sei qual DocType utilizar. Posso utilizar o DocType de HTML5?

Comment: Qual versão do PrimeFaces você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver na versão 5 ou superior, pode usar o `<!DOCTYPE html>` para HTML5.

O próprio [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) faz isso, além de enfatizar no item *Components* que os componentes são compatíveis com HTML5.

Claro, isso não significa que um ou outro componente não vai dar problema. Só que isso aconteceria de qualquer jeito, pois o PF sempre tem componentes "bugados". ;)

Se estiver com uma versão anterior, infelizmente não há garantias, pois não há uma tabela de compatibilidade ou histórico detalhado.